# Nashorn vs Javascript vs ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, java

Java8 provides Next-Generation JavaScript Engine as nashorn.
We can get this engine with following code:

```
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager(); 
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

But i found that **javascript** and **ECMAScript** are also valid parameters for getEngineByName()

```
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("javascript");
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
```

**My queries are:**

- What are the differences between Nashorn, JavaScript and ECMAScript engines?
- Do java provide other engines?
- Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 3):

`Javascript` and `ECMAScript` are aliases for default JavaScript engine bundled with JVM. Java 8+ includes `Nashorn` engine, previous versions were using Rhino engine ("rhino"). `Nashorn` is much faster than `Rhino`, because it is compiling JavaScript into bytecode, instead of running in interpreter mode.

The fastest solution I know of to run JavaScript within JVM is J2V8 (https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8). JavaScript code runs within the `V8` engine, the same one as is used by Node.js and Chrome. In our tests, it's about 2-3 times faster than Nashorn.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure about that fast comparison. I just read a [benchmark](https://lemnik.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/is-nashorn-jvm-faster-than-node-v8/) says more than that