# how to parse an input string such as "4>1", resolve the expression and return boolean

Tags: java, string, parsing, boolean-expression

I am learning Java now and don't know how to convert an input string(such as `"4>1"`) to get a boolean return.

The goal that I want to achieve is that, let Java return `boolean`(true/false) based on the user input, which is in `String`?

For example, I tried to get a return value of "`true`" for input "`!(4>=10)`".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Maybe see here for more informations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143343/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-the-python-eval-function

Comment: Okay sorry but I think I still have some problems with this..;_; For now, I tried 

String userInput = input.next(); 
boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(userInput); 
System.out.print(result);

I typed "4<10" for test and it returns false

Comment: Please take a look at my Nashorn solution. I am a bit amazed myself, how well it works. :) lol

Comment: @SuyeShen, did you find the answer you were looking for? I left an optional answer with simple code example below.

Comment: Try MathParser.org-mXparser.
http://mathparser.org/
http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/evaluating-relations/

Code sample
Expression e = new Expression("4>1");
double doubleResult = e.calculate();
boolean boolResult = false;
if (doubleResult == 1) boolResult = true;

Comment: MathParser.org-mXparser cannot evaluate logical operators. Only Mathematical operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no easy answer

For starters there are no easy solutions. I noticed somebody mentioning `Boolean.valueOf(...)`;

The goal of the `Boolean.valueOf(String)` method is not to evaluate conditions or equations. It is just a simple method to convert a `String` with value `"true"` or `"false"` to a `Boolean` object.

Anyway, if you want this kind of functionality, you have to set some clear limitations. *(note: some equations have no answer: "0/0 = 0/0")*

## Regex parsing

If you are simply comparing integers with integers, then you could assume that the equations will always be in the following format:

```
<integer1>[whitespace]<operator>[whitespace]<integer2>
```

Then, what you could do, is split your string in 3 parts using a regular expression.

```
public static boolean evaluate(String input)
{
  Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*([<>=]+)\\s*(\\d+)");
  Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(input);
  if (matcher.matches())
  {
    String leftPart = matcher.group(1);
    String operatorPart = matcher.group(2);
    String rightPart = matcher.group(3);

    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(leftPart);
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(rightPart);

    if (operatorPart.equals("<")) return i1 < i2;
    if (operatorPart.equals(">")) return i1 > i2;
    if (operatorPart.equals("=")) return i1 == i2;
    if (operatorPart.equals("<=")) return i1 <= i2;
    if (operatorPart.equals(">=")) return i1 >= i2;

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid operator '" + operatorPart + "'");
  }

  throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid format");
}
```

## Script Engines

Java also supports script engines (e.g. Nashorn [and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267869/nashorn-vs-javascript-vs-ecmascript)). These engines can call javascript methods, such as the [`eval(...)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) javascript method, which is exactly what you need. So, this is probably a better solution.

```
public static boolean evaluate(String input)
{
  try
  {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Object result = engine.eval("eval('" + input + "');");
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(result);
  }
  catch (ScriptException e)
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid format");
  }
}
```

This solution can handle more complicated input, such as `"!(4>=10)"`.

*Note: for security reasons, you may want to strip specific characters from the user input. (e.g. the `'` character)*